# reading .doc file takes very long time

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have this code to read .doc file ( not .docx )

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
 object path = FileToSave_path + FileNameToSave + ".doc";
 object readOnly = true;
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
 string totaltext = "";
 ExtractedHTML = docs.Content.Text;
```

but the execution of reading the file hangs here ( more than 10 hours )

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
```

never opens the file, never throws and exception, my file size is 3Mb. I opened the file it has some errors in its fonts. How Can I give the opening of (.doc) file a timeout exception ? or to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you open other doc files?

Comment: Yes, My code is working fine.

Comment: Do you have the path created correctly? For me this `object path = FileToSave_path + FileNameToSave + ".doc";` looks suspicious, I would rather go with `object path = Path.Combine(FileToSave_path, FileNameToSave + ".doc");`  I'm talking `System.IO.Path.Combine` method here.

Comment: the code is working fine for other files , I have tested it hundreds of times. the path is correct.

Comment: Can you open the doc-file manually? If so, try to resave it and replace the troublesome file

Comment: Did you try running your piece of code with elevated privileges - Run as admin?

Comment: yes I can open it , but the problem is that I download the file from Internet ( send some word and get results, then I extract the files dynamically ) I can open this file and resave it, but what about other files in the future, I have to solve the problem, my program opens many files at a time , and can't guess when this will happen. thanks

Comment: I can ignore reading this file, I have many others, but how to move the execution to new file, it hangs here

Comment: In that case I'm guessing that the user/service that runs the interop instsance of winword.exe doesn't have sufficient rights to read the document.

Comment: I download it from the Internet and save it to the path. and read it, I did that for hundreds of files, all are working , but this file is not.

Comment: Then you are asking us how to run it in a separate thread with a timeout set to some timeout. `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { **INSERT-YOUR-CODE-HERE** }).Wait(200);` Other scenarios to mention are explicitely using `Thread`, explicitely using `Task` and maybe using `BackGroundWorker` could do for you aswell.

Comment: What is the actual file path passed to the Open method?

Do you see the delay when you open the file manually?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev the path is correct, this procedure is tested for many files

Comment: Do you see the delay when you open the file manually?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev no, there is no delay. but there is a message when opening the file says that there is something wrong with fonts

Comment: Make sure filename does not contain weird characters, any nonusual whitespaces or non-`utf8` things? To your fonts problem -  one more idea is, if you open this file and then explicitely save it as `UTF-8` or even `UTF-32`, try opening your code after this is performed, maybe it could help. If you cannot succeed in opening the file by hand, try doing it programmatically (but dont operate the file with the MS.Interop library, operate it as a normal file. `1. string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(path, initialEncoding);` then `2. File.WriteAllText(path, fileContents, utf8);`